# Open Selected Pivot Detail or create new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need a VBA code that will open a certain Pivot field's details on a new page or if that field is not found in the pivot table, will create a new sheet that will be named what that field was supposed to be named. I keep getting compile error: End if without block if what am I missing?? This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Macro6
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="+ Deposit", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
If A = Found.Address Then
Range(A).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True
Sheets("Sheet5").Name = "Deposits"
Else: Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Sheet5").Name = "Deposits"
End If

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="- Withdrawal", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
If A = Found.Address Then
Range(A).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True
Sheets("Sheet6").Name = "Withdrawals"
Else: Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Sheet6").Name = "Withdrawals"
End If

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="- Check", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
If A = Found.Address Then
Range(A).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True
Sheets("Sheet7").Name = "Checks"
Else: Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Sheet7").Name = "Checks"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with what you have here. Seeing as this is Macro6, have you got any other code in your workbook that could be causing this?

Comment: No, all the other macros I use are completely unrelated to this one. Also, what I am noticeing is that instead of actually selecting the cell I want it to open from the pivot table, the macro is just going straight to the create new sheet for each and nameing the new sheets. The code is breaking down at the line      If A = Found.Address Then

Answer (score 0):

1. Select desired cell from Pivot table.
2. Show Selected Cell with ShowDetail. This will create new sheet.
3. Rename newly created sheet with your desired name. (Newly sheet will be activated sheet)

   ```
   Cells(TargetRow, TargetColumn).Select
   Selection.ShowDetail = True
   ActiveSheet.Name = "YourNew Sheet Name"
   ```

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Macro10()
'
' Macro10 Macro
'
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Range("A4").Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="+ Deposit", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart,    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
On Error GoTo NoDeposit
A = Found.Address
Range(A).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True


Withdrawals:
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Range("A4").Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="- Withdrawal", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
On Error GoTo NoWithdrawal
A = Found.Address
Range(A).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True


Checks:   
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Range("A4").Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="- Check", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
On Error GoTo NoCheck
A = Found.Address
Range(A).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True


Labels:

Sheets("Sheet5").Name = "Deposits"
Sheets("Sheet6").Name = "Withdrawals"
Sheets("Sheet7").Name = "Checks"




Exit Sub
NoDeposit: 
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Resume Withdrawals:

NoWithdrawal: Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Resume Checks:

NoCheck: Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Resume Labels:


End Sub
```